# $.ajax calls don't go through on android devices

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Javascript code:

```
                var googledocsurl = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";
                $.ajax({
                    url: window.localStorage.getItem('basePath') + 'pdf/GetPdfUrls',
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { id: window.localStorage.getItem('userid') },
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function () { $.mobile.loading('show'); },
                    success: function (returnValue) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < returnValue.length; i++) {
                            $('#pdfList').append("<li><a onclick=\"window.open('" + googledocsurl + window.localStorage.getItem('basePath') + returnValue[i].pdfUri + "\', '_blank', 'location=yes')\">" + returnValue[i].PdfCreationDate + "</a></li>")
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {

                    },
                    complete: function () { $.mobile.loading('hide'); },
                })
```

if i try this ajax call on the emulator and ripply it works no problem but as so on as i try it on my android device it works like 1/50 times,  it's kind of inconsistent and this makes it really hard to fix or understand

The error that i can see in Visual Studio

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
GetPdfUrls(0,0)
```

and if i click "GetPdfUrls(0,0)" i can see the response and it's populated with data but for some reason this gives me and error but as far as i can see it's all right to me(especially sens it works 1 out of 50 times i try)

The response:

```
[{"pdfUri":"Image/GetPdf/8259ff54-6cd2-48dd-a0dc-d39b255e9bad","PdfCreationDate":"2014-12-08"},{"pdfUri":"Image/GetPdf/f05ff375-45e2-429b-a8fc-2c9d660df263","PdfCreationDate":"2014-12-08"},{"pdfUri":"Image/GetPdf/211feab8-9715-4942-bf8c-f7e95188c987","PdfCreationDate":"2014-12-08"},{"pdfUri":"Image/GetPdf/6ded622b-2d3e-4151-8be3-01070d1b9d69","PdfCreationDate":"2014-12-08"},{"pdfUri":"Image/GetPdf/f34adfa9-7bbf-4db9-b7ee-92fd619b0dc0","PdfCreationDate":"2014-12-08"},{"pdfUri":"Image/GetPdf/b6e5e56c-68d3-4662-a00e-b11dc09bfd9a","PdfCreationDate":"2014-12-08"},{"pdfUri":"Image/GetPdf/cc633e61-adcd-414d-bfc7-d09a30e05b01","PdfCreationDate":"2014-12-15"}]
```

if you need more info just ask and ill try my best to provide!
Thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: Try clean and the rebuild the solution. Surround it with try catch block and see if you are getting any response or not.

Comment: Any chance that it's trying this ajax call before basePath or userid is saved to local storage?

Comment: @ClaytonLeis if that was the case then the response would be empty and not contain data right?

Comment: Can it be something wrong with the phone? because now it works again...

Comment: Right, you wouldn't be getting any JSON data if that was the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well don't i feel stupid now...

Seams like the phone don't have any internet when it's not connected to a wifi network and it seams to loses the connection to the router at random and connect to another wifi network (with no internet connection) that have the same signal strength and then change back at random (guess it take the known network with the best signal strength).

I was lucky i watch the logcat log and saw this change happen other wise i would have been stuck for a while :/

Anyway thanks all for your help!