# Phonegap external link not working in app

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I am not able to open simple external link in phonegap application.
Here's my source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <h2><a href="https://google.com">Fiberon</a></h2>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And config xml

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.phonegap.myapp" version="1.0.0">
  <name>MyApp</name>
  <description>Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
  <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="*"/>
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Note, I do not want to open external link in other browser or app browsre, Just want to load that other external urls. It does not works in Android for me.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The last meta tag in your html is responsible for that. Remove it or modify it to your requirement to make your code works

Comment: I tried removing it. Still does not works

Comment: Are you getting internet access permission from users?

Comment: i am not sure if internet access permission is required. Just to link another external page. It used to work fine in old phonegap. Since, i have the phonegap has updated it does not works.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console? while clicking on that element

Comment: undefined No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.

Comment: Did you refer this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212306/no-content-security-policy-meta-tag-found-error-in-my-phonegap-application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102826/discussion-between-ashok-shah-and-rajaprabhu-aravindasamy).