# Ionic - No content security policy error

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Developing android app using Ionic framework,
Implementing Push notification on it.

1. Installed ngCordova and included in index.html
2. Installed cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git

getting following error.

No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.
but if i check in plugins directory i could found cordova-plugin-whitelist. do i need to configure anywhere?

Comment: in index.html add this tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">` and check it

Comment: A duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212306/no-content-security-policy-meta-tag-found-error-in-my-phonegap-application