# Adreno error crashes Android cordova app on select dropdown

Tags: android, cordova

My Android cordova-based app crashes on an Motorola Droid Turbo 2, Android Version 6.0.  The app runs fine on many other devices/platforms - including my android phone.  I can crash the app by making a selection in a completely barebones dropdown.

ADDITIONAL DETAILS (new 5/27/16): 1.) The app does not always crash the first time.  Sometimes he can tap on 2 or 3 dropdowns. 2.) The user has another app on his phone, which I built with the same architecture, and it runs fine.

UPDATE:  I finally followed USKMobility's tip and handled the whitelist error I had been getting, and got different message right before the app crashes. I have updated them in the block below.

Here are the crucial logcat lines. They start with when I tap the dropdown.

```
04-30 11:28:26.619: W/Adreno-GSL(9728): <gsl_ldd_control:475>: ioctl fd 38 code 0x40180917 (IOCTL_KGSL_CMDSTREAM_FREEMEMONTIMESTAMP_CTXTID) failed: errno 22 Invalid argument
04-30 11:28:26.620: W/Adreno-GSL(9728): <gsl_ldd_control:475>: ioctl fd 38 code 0x40180917 (IOCTL_KGSL_CMDSTREAM_FREEMEMONTIMESTAMP_CTXTID) failed: errno 16 Device or resource busy
04-30 11:28:26.635: I/Adreno(9728): DequeueBuffer: dequeueBuffer failed
04-30 11:28:26.692: W/google-breakpad(9728): Microdump crash handler failed.
04-30 11:28:26.707: A/libc(9728): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x7f576c0000 in tid 9780 (Chrome_InProcGp)
```

Another update is that I the app no longer crashes consistently on the first time I use a dropdown.  Sometimes I can use 3-5 dropdowns before it crashes.  Ideas?

Comment: add meta tag to find exact problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212306/no-content-security-policy-meta-tag-found-error-in-my-phonegap-application

Comment: I added the meta tag and the whitelist messag went away, but the subject of this post is unchanged.  I have updated the post.

Comment: @pdschuller I feel the key hint of this issue lies in your last logcat line - "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x7f576c0000 in tid 9780 (Chrome_InProcGp)" This seems to be more of hardware driver issue than the application issue. May be a driver update could be the fix. Request you to have a look at this link - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=498947 Hope it helps. Keep us posted

Comment: @pdschuller Did you had a check on that? Did that help?

Comment: Why don´t add some of your code?

Comment: @pdschuller Awaiting your response.

Comment: @pdschuller Did you cracked it finally?

Comment: @Gandhi: The user just informed me that he did all he could with updating the drivers, and even went to his carrier's store to have them try that, and there was no change.  The app still crashes when he makes a selection in a dropdown.  btw, it does not always crash the first time.  Sometimes he can tap on 2 or 3 dropdowns.

Comment: @pdschuller but did you confirmed that Qualcomm have released a driver fix for the same?

Comment: @Gandhi: No. But the user said the Verizon staffer he talked to told him that there was no way to update the Qualcomm driver.

Comment: @pdschuller but the link I sent you states that the only one way to fix this issue is to update driver as its more of driver issue than application issue and that's why it's device specific. Anyways the bounty on this question is gone too :( gud luck