# deviceready not firing in Cordova app on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I have index.html where I have `deviceready` event listener added to script tag. But it is not triggered on loading the HTML. Instead, when clicking the home button it is triggered from `onAppDidEnterBackground` method in `CDVViewController`.

I wanted to call my custom plugin to get the values which I am trying to populate in the HTML loaded. I found few solutions asking to change the meta tag. I did try changing, but no use. It is not working in iOS9 also. I guess the meta tag issue is from iOS10. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Cordova v4.4.0

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: http://* 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <title>My HTML Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src='cordova.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='CustomPlugin.js'></script>
        <script>
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            window.plugins.CustomPlugin.myMethod(function (result) {
                document.getElementById('Name').value = result['Name'];
            }, function (error) {
                alert(error);
            });
        }, false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='article'>
            <div class='tableWrapper'>
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class='right'>CName:</td>
                    <td colspan='3'><input type='text' id='Name'/></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using an alert to test whether the event is firing or not.

Comment: Nope. It doesn’t. It does fire when I click home button..

Answer (score 3):

If you're having the same problem I was, then this is related to your content-security-policy meta tag. I used the one below from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918553/cordova-deviceready-not-firing-in-ios-until-interacting-with-ios), and problem solved.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data:* gap://* tel:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your addEventListener into a function onLoad and call it with onload event in your body tag :

```
    function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady(){
           //the code you want to execute
    }
```

and

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

Because if you do it your way, you're trying to do the deviceready event before the cordova library had been loaded.

Comment: Tried that as well. onLoad function is not called, but deviceready event is not triggered. :(

Comment: What if you put your script javascripts cordova.js at the last position, because it is before your customplugin.js, and when the onload event fire, cordova.js might be loaded but not your customplugin.js

Comment: I tried adding Cordova.js after customplugin.js. It doesn't work.

Comment: try to execute that command in your project directory "cordova platform remove ios"
"cordova platform add ios"

Comment: If something is wrong, it shouldn't call deviceready event at all right? It is fired when it loses focus, like pressing home button, long press to open Siri etc.,

Comment: I am breaking my head since two days now. Tried all possible solutions available in the internet. :(

Comment: have you tried with a simple example ? like just call ondeviceready and alert('hello world !'), in a new project 
And is your method working correctly ?

Comment: Its both native and Cordova based application. Some part of it is native and some part Cordova. I have problem only with this html file. Its working fine in other areas.

Comment: Now device ready event is fired.. But plugins doesn’t work.. Tried changing meta tag.. But no luck.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe it's because your js file isn't loaded when your deviceready is fired, i would suggest you to use jquery and put your addeventlistener inside the $(document).ready(function(){  }  that's what I used to do when i was doing some cordova and i never had problem

Comment: I used some of the answer from this topic when I started :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576062/jquery-document-ready-vs-phonegap-deviceready

Answer (score 0):

Load all your script on the bottom of html body

```
<html lang="en">
<head>...</head>
<body>
  <div>Your content here</div>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src='CustomPlugin.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='cordova.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='main.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and create main.js file then put your code in there..

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", firstInitCordova, true);
};

function firstInitCordova(){
    if(!window.cordova){
        // If cordova is not defined then call this function again after 2 second
        setTimeout(firstInitCordova, 2000);
        return;
    }

    //console.log(window.plugins);
    window.plugins.CustomPlugin.myMethod(function (result) {
        document.getElementById('Name').value = result['Name'];
    }, function (error) {
        alert(error);
    });
}

// If you're unsure then set a timer
setTimeout(function(){
    firstInitCordova();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I tried your way as well. firstInitCordova calls only after going background and coming foreground.