# $(...).each is not a function

Tags: jquery, each, typeerror

I'm trying to get the text inside all **h2** tags on a page, using the web console.

All I've found says to use each, I've tried

```
var anArray = [];

$('h2').each( function(i,e) {
    anArray.push($(e).innerHTML);
});
```

But it returns `TypeError: $(...).each` is not a function.

I've also tried using

```
$.each('h2', function(i,e) {
        anArray.push($(e).innerHTML);
    });
```

But again, all I get is `TypeError: $.each` is not a function?

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery?

Comment: also to get html from "e" which is element here you should unwrap jquery object to DOM element using e.get(0) or e[0] .

Comment: I guess, $('h2').innerHTML works to get the first h2 tag, so I suppose jQuery should be loaded?

Comment: Ah ok, I guess it wasn't loaded.. it works now, thank you.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This question helped me solve a problem. Productive downvoting! At least, an explanation...

Comment: I got an error like this, but like @M.Sa, I was able to do some jQuery actions. The problem turned out to be that my console was targeting one of my extensions instead of "top"

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**1)** Paste:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

on your console (includes jQuery)

**2)** Wait 1 sec and paste:

```
var h2Arr = [];
$('h2').each( function() {
    h2Arr.push($(this).html());
});
```

Now, all contents of h2 tags of that page should be stored into h2Arr

Comment: For this method of loading JQuery to work, you may need to open up the security of the web page by editing the DOM like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59531227/137948

Comment: can be included in single copy-paste too by adding the "wait" via code like so:
setTimeout(() => {  <the code in 2nd part> }, 1000);

Answer (score 22):

if you write code like without $() 
for example

```
var1.each(function(){}) //its wrong//each function is not defined error

$(var1).each(function(){}) //its right
```

Comment: I had an array after split(). I was chaining it directly with .each() instead of wrapping it with $() first

Answer (score 5):

> Note: For Chrome, do not expect $ is always `jQuery`.

You can put `$` into console to check if it returns default `ƒ $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }`, if yes means $ is not defined for `jQuery`.

Luckily that we have below ways to try:

1. **Solve the conflict of using `$`, let it be `jQuery` without any ambiguity**

Firstly, you can put this code snippet

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js";  /* Include any online jquery library you need */
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
```

into the Console, 
then put `$.noConflict` into console, if it not returns `undefined`, but returns `ƒ (t){return e.$===w&&(e.$=Kt),t&&e.jQuery===w&&(e.jQuery=Jt),w}`, it means `$` is not defined for `JQuery` now.

Next you can continue to input your regional code, then you will find it works well now.

**Refer**: https://blog.wplauncher.com/run-jquery-in-chrome-console/

2. **Using `.js` file instead in Chrome, then debug the JavaScript file.**

**Refer:** [Chrome DevTools Snippets](http://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/)

3. **Besides, for some specific version of Chrome, there is a option in UI to set the `page context`** (**probably removed** this function in latest version!)

[image: img].

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of this error is because JQuery is not included in your website, that's why it shows this error. You have to include JQuery in your website or rewrite your code in vanilla js.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .html() instead of .innerHTML:

```
$.each($('h2'), function(index, value){
   alert($(value).html());
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mqemg4vk/) a working fiddle.

Comment: I'm still getting  $.each is not a function when trying it on a web page.

Comment: Ok. So there is a problem with your jQuery. Maybe, as already mentioned in comments, you didn't load jQuery yet. Can you please post all your code?