# How to fix '301 Moved Permanently' when try to load js/css in local directories in a php server?

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm setting up a local Chevereto server (https://chevereto.com/free) for my Homework. After successfully downloaded the whole application, I run it with php -S localhost:8080. However it only shows plain HTML text without CSS and Javascript. I have no such problem when I set this up one month ago.

I have done some research on this and believe this is more of a browser problem. I set up a php script with a javascript in another file. When I run the script with php -S, the network tab show the request for the javascript file returned the index.php instead of the javascript. I am not sure if this is a similar problem though.

After I ran php -S and visit http://localhost:8080/ 
I open console and find this warning on:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/lib/Peafowl/peafowl.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/app/content/system/style.css">
```

With this warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/app/content/system/install".
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/lib/Peafowl/install".
```

And this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.each is not a function
    at install:58
    at install:58
```

While the source clearly has:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/lib/Peafowl/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/lib/Peafowl/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

And those files exist on my computer.

While looking at the request for the CSS/Javascript files, I see this:

```
General: 
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/lib/Peafowl/peafowl.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response:
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2019 09:40:44 +0000
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Host: localhost:8080
Location: http://localhost:8080/lib/Peafowl/install
Pragma: no-cache
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.25
```

Do anyone know how to fix it? Huge thanks.

Comment: Try pressing `CTR+SHIFT+R` on your or `F5`

Comment: _“I'm setting up a local Chevereto server”_ - that is not really a “server”, that is an image hosting script. _“I run it with php -S localhost:8080”_ - I don’t know if you can expect that to work, such a script might rely on URL rewriting and other features that are not available using this primitive built-in “PHP server”. I’d suggest you go install a proper web server, XAMP/WAMP.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s) might help

Comment: Thank you all. But chrome suddenly decided to fix itself and it can load CSS/Javascript now, I believe it's a similar case that @ThumChoonTat linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Add `type` to your `stylesheet`,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/lib/Peafowl/peafowl.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/app/content/system/style.css">
```

And jquery `each` is only applicable for arrays, Refer this,
[$(...).each is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912136/each-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I think it is a cache problem mentioned by @Thum Choon Tat above, chrome itself seems to fixed it automatically out of a sudden. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Chrome decided it fix itself, probably because of cache expiring.
As @Thum Choon Tat mentioned above, it should a similar problem to [How long do browsers cache HTTP 301s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s).