# Content Security Policy directive violated on a simple website

Tags: javascript, google-maps, content-security-policy

Sorry to bother you but I'm working on my personnal website and trying to integrate a Google Map (thank you codepen for the great templates).

But I have to face a recurrent CSP error message, leading the map not to load:

> Refused to load the script
>   'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBlSsS5JzdJLsuMEY24xeLAZOc7JAH6sr8'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com".

I made reseaches before asking my question, as it seems to be a problem for quite some people. I tried everything, including removing the Google Analytics script and addind this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com www.google-analytics.com ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'">
```

But it didn't change anything. My map won't load, and it kind of pisses me of !

Do you have any idea what I made wrong ? Thanks a lot for your help !
(if needed, I can show you the error in live, but I don't want to "promote" my site here)

Comment: Can you post the HTML of (one of) the page(s) in question?

Comment: Sure: http://www.aymericbazire.com Thanks!

Comment: @RichO'Kelly you obviously meant the code... Stupid me. Here you are: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B05bkTIQj7DBZXF4bWRILXp5UlE&usp=sharing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31211359/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 479 of your `.htaccess` file says:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com"
```

Not sure your `meta` tag can override this.

You should probably modify that line in your `.htaccess` file instead, to include your other sources (in the case of Google Maps, "`https://maps.googleapis.com`").

Comment: Thank you very much I would have never found out without you !

Comment: De rien et bon courage ! :-)