# Refused to connect to URL because of violation of Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

This is the error in my console:
[image: this is the error in my console]

This is the actual code of the meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src &apos;self&apos; data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com ; style-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos;; media-src *">
```

I am developing an android app in cordova. I am trying to retrive data from the scratched URL in the photo. this is the index.html

```
html>
<head>
<body>


        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the index.js

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
      document.addEventListener('loadcities', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    app.receivedEvent('loadcities');
},

// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
  if (id === 'deviceready') {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);}
    else if (id === 'loadcities') {
      var url = "http://uiiuh"
        $.getJSON(url).done(function(response){
                    if(!response.length){
                        console.warn("Empty list of cities");
                    }
                    config.cities = response;
                    $('body').trigger('city-data');
                }).fail(function(data, status, error){
                    console.error("Something went wrong retrieving the cities via API")
                });
        }

    }

};
```

app.initialize();

I want to show the retrieved data only in console for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211359/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po  
Add more details of what you're trying to do : what are you developping ? Website ? Android App ? With Node ? Cordova ?  
Show some code (more than that), we just don't know what you're talking about. Only one meta tag isn't sufficient to understand what your problem is.

Comment: You do not actually state what your question is.

Comment: Are you appending the script that makes this `http` call to a hosted page?

Comment: You are right 
I added something more explanatory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Content-Security-Policy restricts [`connect-src`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#directive-connect-src) to `self`, `data:`, `gap:` (is that a Cordova thing?), and `https://ssl.gstatic.com` — this means that any attempt at loading a resource from a URL that doesn't match one of this will be blocked.

Since the script tries to load JSON data from `http://uiiuh`, it is blocked; you need to add `http://uiiuh` to the list of allowed sources in the CSP rule.