# Content Security Policy works as expected on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: mobile-safari, content-security-policy

Having a content security policy on one's website is a good way to provide an extra layer of security on one's site.

I have a content security policy that works as expected on desktop, but it breaks the site on mobile (safari). The content security policy is inside meta tags. I am using nonces and hashes.  On mobile I get the error stating that it refused to execute inline script because it violates the Content Security Policy directive which includes the hashes and nonces.  The error also states that I need either a hash or nonce in the code to execute the code, but they are already present there, and that's how it works well on desktop. The problem is that on mobile it's acting as if the hashes and nonces didn't exist.  Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Code helps. At least show us the CSP, and the nonces in the script tag

Comment: You didn’t specify what mobile browser, but if you’re talking Safari, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49163882/339440

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks but it works well in Safari when it's on desktop.  The problem is only on mobile.

Comment: Again, please show us your code.  Let’s see the CSP itself.  Have you tried it on multiple iOS devices?  Made sure the devices aren’t running any content filters?

Comment: I’ve had CSP troubles with iPads running an old version of iOS (9 and earlier). There’s a fix; but let me know if that’s the issue first....

Comment: Yep!!!  It's because of an old operating system!  I updated the OS, and it works as expected! What's the fix for old OS? Thank you!  =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CSP, if you include a nonce for `script-src` or `style-src`, `unsafe-inline` will be ignored *if the browser understands nonces*.  Therefore, in order to be compatible with older browsers that don't understand CSP2 (for example, Safari on iOS 9 and earlier), include both your nonce AND `unsafe-inline`.

The newer browsers will follow the nonce and ignore the `unsafe-inline`.  The older browsers will not understand the nonce, and thus fall back to the `unsafe-inline`.

See https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/strict-csp.html

> script-src nonce-{random} 'unsafe-inline'
>
> The nonce directive means that  elements will be allowed to execute only if they contain a nonce attribute matching the randomly-generated value which appears in the policy.
>
> Note: In the presence of a CSP nonce the unsafe-inline directive will be ignored by modern browsers. Older browsers, which don't support nonces, will see unsafe-inline and allow inline scripts to execute.

Comment: Thanks.  =)  Is 'unsafe-inline' written before or after the nonce?

Comment: I don’t think it should matter. `script-src self 'nonce-xxxxxxxxxxxx' 'unsafe-inline';`