# Refused to frame 'https://api.xxx.jp/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, manifest.json

Here we go:
I am new to google's chrome extension development, so please bear with me.

I have an extension which is giving me the following error:

> Refused to frame 'https://api.xxx.jp/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' https://staticxx.facebook.com https://twitter.com https://*.twimg.com https://5415703.fls.doubleclick.net https://player.vimeo.com https://pay.twitter.com https://www.facebook.com https://ton.twitter.com https://syndication.twitter.com https://vine.co twitter: https://www.youtube.com https://platform.twitter.com https://upload.twitter.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://4337974.fls.doubleclick.net https://8122179.fls.doubleclick.net https://donate.twitter.com".

My *manifest.json* file has the following settings regarding *Content Security Policy*:

```
{
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
   "manifest_version": 2,
}
```

In my *content.js* file, I'm calling an api through inside an *iframe* tag:

```
<iframe src="'+url+'" name="xxxExtensionsFrame" width="380" height="' + (heightBase - 5) + '" border="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The api's *url* is always in https form.

- This extension works for most websites but in some websites like https://twitter.com/?lang=en, it displays a gray pop up box with the error message described above.

[image: Gray pop up box]
Please help me find the solution to this issue.

Here is an example of my extension at work:

```html
<video class="image-viewer horizontal" poster="https://thumb.gyazo.com/thumb/642_w/_262d5667a035ff8505079ce6994d3c3f-gif.jpg" autoplay="" playsinline="" loop="" style="max-width: 642px; max-height: 100%;"><source src="https://i.gyazo.com/90701bdda37df8282699208efaa215a5.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211359/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po

Comment: @noogui Not a duplicate, I have checked all other solutions but none addresses the issue of frame/iframe. If you know how to solve it, please provide a specific answer.

Answer (score 5):

Twitter uses `Content-Security-Policy` header. The only solution to your problem is to modify response headers using the `chrome.webRequest` API in your background script.

Here is an example:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(info => {
    const headers = info.responseHeaders; // original headers
    for (let i=headers.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
        let header = headers[i].name.toLowerCase();
        if (header === "content-security-policy") { // csp header is found
            // modify frame-src here
            headers[i].value = headers[i].value.replace("frame-src", "frame-src https://domain-you-want-to-iframe.com/");
        }
    }
    // return modified headers
    return {responseHeaders: headers};
}, {
    urls: [ "<all_urls>" ], // match all pages
    types: [ "sub_frame" ] // for framing only
}, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);
```

Example is extracted from my blog post [here](https://usamaejaz.com/bypassing-security-iframe-webextension/).

Comment: @Josimar Lopes can you please mark the answer as solution so the question doesn't show up in unanswered questions anymore?