# Ajax response from Twitter to Flask server shows error

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, flask

I am using a flask server to get AJAX response from a twitter page. I am sending the response as follows:

```
var getRes = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "http://localhost:5000/myApp",
      data: vals,
      contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      success: function(res) { console.log(res) }
});
```

When the response is sent to the server it is showing me the following lines:

> Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:5000/myApp' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src

I checked other SO questions regarding the same topic e.g., [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211359/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po) where they mentioned to add meta tags in the html. As i am working with Twitter, how can I do the same?

Comment: Is your `myApp` html have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="???` these ?

Comment: @RajaSimon myApp is a flask application. How can i add the following html to it?

Comment: Sorry is your html content have the meta tag or not ?