# How to use meta tag for resolving Content security policy issue for loading an external script

Tags: meta-tags, meta, content-security-policy

I am trying to load google maps through an external script (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyABsNkQCBQ6oq0vqSJ8JyogrVXq2Ot0CaA) in the browser which gives the following content security policy error:

*"Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyABsNkQCBQ6oq0vqSJ8JyogrVXq2Ot0CaA' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self...."*

So, i tried adding the following meta tag to the html file inside  tag but still getting the same error:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"  
        content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';"/>
```

Comment: You can’t override the policy in the Content-Security-Policy HTTP header with a less-restrictive policy in a meta element in the document itself. You need to instead change the backend server-side code that’s setting the value of the Content-Security-Policy HTTP header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31211359/608639)

Comment: @sideshowbarker. I found the http response to index html page that has "Content security policy" header set which was more restrictive and that's why my script does not load. Thanks for the valuable info.