# Content-Security-Policy problem with bootstrap 4

Tags: cdn, content-security-policy

Hi im currently a beginner in coding and im trying to check my website online with filezilla
the problem im having is the fact that when i upload it in the server im getting this error:

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src https://*.fontawesome.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.
```

the code in my index file that gives the error:

```
 <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
```

does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211359/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po)

Comment: please post your content-security-policy

Answer (score 3):

Your existing Content Security Policy (CSP) for styles is this:

```
style-src https://*.fontawesome.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
```

This policy only allows styles from three locations:

- Stylesheets loaded from Font Awesome's website (`https://*.fontawesome.com`)
- Stylesheets loaded from your own website (`'self'`)
- Styles defined in-line (e.g., in a `<style>` tag)

The problem is that your page is attempting to load Bootstrap's stylesheet from their CDN, which is a completely different website.  To fix the problem, you'll have to do one of two things:

1. Host `bootstrap.css` on your own site, or
2. Add Bootstrap's CDN to your Content Security Policy, like so:

   `style-src https://*.fontawesome.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com 'self' ;`

Comment: I don't think that `unsafe-inline` should be there. `unsafe-inline` should be avoided as much as possible. If the OP has it in their code, I don't see it and it shouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: I agree that `unsafe-inline` shouldn't be used, and although one could argue that it isn't relevant to the question, I do agree that its use should be discouraged.  The OP most likely added it because of Font Awesome... if they did, they should follow [this guidance from Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/security).

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I read the OPs question and hadn't seen that they had used `unsafe-inline`, I thought it was a usage you'd introduced. Sorry.