# electron quick start Refused to connect to 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'

Tags: node.js, electron

i'm trying use google drive API quickstart project inside electron. here's my sample project:
[electron quickstart with google api](https://github.com/dhanyn10/electron-example/tree/gdrive/gdrive)

> how it should works:
> when click authorize button, it'll redirected to authUrl then we can copy the authorization key, insert the authorization key page to input with id 'key'

when i run from electron,its return following error:

```
D:\koding\electron-example\gdrive\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:68 Refused to connect to 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered from this post [refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211359/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po)

we need to specify which kind of address that will allowed by content security