# Google Chrome "Refused to load the script" error in Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome, asp.net-core

I have observed the following error on Chrome Dev Console even if using Incognito Window:

*Refused to load the script 'https://localhost:5001/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'sha256-ZT3q7lL9GXNGhPTB1Vvrvds2xw/kOV0zoeok2tiV23I='". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.*

I have a look at the causes and commonly browser extensions are reported, but in Incognito Window, there is not any extension, etc. So, any fix related to the problem?

Comment: The **Content Security Policy** in different versions of chrome is different. After upgrading chrome, check if it will occur to this problem.

Comment: Yes, I checked but Chrome already updated and re-test again still the problem occurs. Very strange to see that even on Incognito :(

Comment: @Karney. Any other idea to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the security policy, for example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' https://localhost:5001 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

Or only

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://localhost:5001 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

Chrome has the CSP (Content Security Policy).

> - You can't use inline scripting in your Chrome App pages. The restriction bans both  blocks and event handlers ().
> - You can't reference any external resources in any of your app files (except for video and audio resources). You can't embed external resources in an iframe.
> - You can't use string-to-JavaScript methods like eval() and new Function().

Here is the policy value:

```
default-src 'self';
connect-src * data: blob: filesystem:;
style-src 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline';
img-src 'self' data:;
frame-src 'self' data:;
font-src 'self' data:;
media-src * data: blob: filesystem:;
```

[More infomation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/contentSecurityPolicy/#relaxing)

Comment: Many thanks. Is it related to adding script reference to angular.json, index.html in Angular app? Or giving reference on .NET Core razor page?

Comment: It should be changed it in angular index.html.

Comment: Any detailed example for the solution please?

Comment: @Lorenzo, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211359/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po), refer to the marked answer.

Comment: the anwser on the link explain almost nothing.

Comment: @Lorenzo, Rocío García Luque's answer more comprehensive.

Comment: I tried both of them your answer and the others on index.html by replacing the necessary part, but not worked.

Comment: @Lorenzo, Try to change `https://localhost` instead of `http://*`.

Comment: Both `https://localhost` and `http://*` [allows standard ports](https://csplite.com/csp4/#host_name_standart_port) only, while is used nonstandard `:5001` port. Only `https://localhost:5001` or `https:` in the `script-src` can fix the issue.

Comment: @Lorenzo, you can change it to this type.