# Adsense sometimes doesn't serve ads because of Content Security Policy

Tags: content-security-policy, adsense

I recently added Google AdSense to my website and the ads works fine, expect sometimes they don't load and I get the following errors in the console

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://cdn.ampproject.org/". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-xxx'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

From what I've read I need to added the CSP in my HTML headers, but doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

**TRY1**

This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211359/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po) could help to get access to the site with the following snippet:

```
script-src 'self' http://xxxx 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
```

**TRY2**

This [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp) will show you how to define the policy with:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com
```

Hope that will help and you question is answered. Give it a shot, cheers! :)

Comment: I would NOT recommend the first solution here, that basically removes the whole point of a CSP. The second solution is a little bit better, it opens up scrips from the Google API domain.

Comment: You are totally right! Try 1 was considered to get it run in the first place. Keeping your comment will help to go with Try 2. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: **UPDATE**: Adsense now appears to use `https://adsense.googleapis.com` [source](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/reference/rest) as of 2024