# Angular youtube player not displaying videos when app is deployed

Tags: angular, iframe, youtube, youtubeplayer

guys!
Ran into interesting behaviour when using angular youtube player(*ngx-youtube-player*
). The video displays perfectly fine when app is running on localhost, but when deployed app is running, video simply doesn't show up in the component. Console shows error `Refused to load the script 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://apis.google.com/"`.
We tried to fix it by adding the following line to our ***index.html***

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src youtube.com www.youtube.com;">
```

but it didn't work. I also noticed that this behaviour is observed only in chrome, in Safari everything is working.

We also tried a different way, by adding `script-src 'self' youtube.com` to meta tag instead, but it throws `Refused to load the script 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' youtube.com". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.`

The code looks like this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { BsModalRef } from "ngx-bootstrap";

@Component({
  selector: "app-video-event",
  templateUrl: "./video-event.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./video-event.component.css"],
})
export class VideoEventComponent implements OnInit {
  videoId: string;
  link: string;

  constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    document.body.appendChild(tag);

    const videoUrl = new URL(this.link);

    this.videoId = new URLSearchParams(videoUrl.search.slice(1)).get("v");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
    <youtube-player class="youtube-player" [videoId]="videoId"></youtube-player>
 </div>
```

Any suggestions on how it can be fixed? It appears that it's a problem with CSP and/or iframe, but I can't find anything helpful apart from solutions already tried.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this issue, but, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31219814/12511801) mentions a possible solution. Have you [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=Refused+to+load+the+script+%27https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fiframe_api%27+because+it+violates+the+following+Content+Security+Policy+directive&rlz=1C1GCEA_enCO941CO941&oq=Refused+to+load+the+script+%27https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fiframe_api%27+because+it+violates+the+following+Content+Security+Policy+directive&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) about this issue? - honest question here.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Hi, and yes, I've tried the solutions suggested there, it didn't help, unfortunately:( Thinking about turning to backend to ask if they can deal with it

Comment: As a suggestion, when you have tried any solution you found, please, add those links - and so, other users can check why the solution didn't work for you. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the way you get that videoid from url parameter. you add that link variable but there is no link.

```js
       const tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
      document.body.appendChild(tag);

      const params = new URL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-jw5BXS9SU').searchParams;
      const vid = params.get('v');
      if (vid) {
        this.videoId = vid;
      }
```

```html
    <youtube-player
          [videoId]="videoId"
          [height]="300"
          [width]="540"
        ></youtube-player>
```

Problem is that

> "link" in ts

this works for me.