# How to call a function in js file from another server in extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm needing to use functions from js file which i keep in another server on ext, but when i embed in style

```js
<script src="http://localhost:3000/weather.js">
```

Then it gives error:

> Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:3000/weather.js' because
> it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem'
> was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

So is there any solution for me? I simply want when I click a button to execute the method located in the weather.js file:

```js
const main = () =>{
    console.log("Success!!!")
}
tets = document.querySelector(".btn-test")
test.onclick = () =>{
    main()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211359/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po)

Comment: this no working for me :(((

Comment: ManifestV3 disallows external scripts by design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the HTML  close tag, you can try it

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="http://localhost:3000/weather.js"></script>
```

I think it will work.

Comment: i just didn't write enough content, my code is still complete but it doesn't work