# CSP Header and Cross domain Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers, cross-domain

my server (my.server.com) produces a HTML page that call another service (external.server.com) for load data.
For the ajax call i'm using jquery.

```
$.ajax({
     url:"https://external.server.com/check",
     dataType: 'get', 
     success:function(json){
         // do stuff with json (in this case an array)
         $("userContainer").append(json);
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     }      
});
```

When i'm trying to call the service i receive a browser error:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://external.server.com/check' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'"
```

In my HTML page i'm loading javascript resources like that:

```
<script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

And my CSP Header configuration is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src my.server.com; script-src 'unsafe-inline' my.server.com; connect-src external.server.com">

<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src my.server.com; script-src 'unsafe-inline' my.server.com; connect-src external.server.com">

<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src my.server.com; script-src 'unsafe-inline' my.server.com; connect-src external.server.com">
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the connect-src policy not the content, as You can see the error is because it refuses to CONNECT, to solve that add:

```
Content-Security-Policy: connect-src 'self' https://external.server.com/check;
```

Make sure you add the full URL including http://....etc

For more information go to https://content-security-policy.com/connect-src/

Answer (score 0):

use "default-src  *"

**you can follow the below link its's may be helpful for you.**

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852682/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po)

Comment: Hi Raju, i receive the same error : Refused to connect to 'https://external.server.com/check' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback. Thanks