# Cannot read property 'request' of undefined electron.js

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to make my electron application send a request to a website, presumably on the renderer thread. I have tried to following code stated on the [docs itself](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/client-request) and I seem to encounter the following error: `Cannot read property 'request' of undefined`

This is the code:

```
  const { app } = require('electron')
  const { net } = require('electron')
  const request = net.request('https://github.com')
  request.on('response', (response) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`)
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`)
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`)
    })
    response.on('end', () => {
      console.log('No more data in response.')
    })
  })
  request.end()
```

Comment: `app.whenReady().then(() => {`. you have missed this line.

Comment: `net` is a main process only API, you are trying to use it in the renderer process (index.html) this is not and will not be supported. In the renderer process use `fetch`  instead

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I get exactly the same error message when I tried to use `net` from the renderer process so I assume you did the same. As a quote from electron GitHub issue page: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/25384

> `net` is the main process only API, you are trying to use it in the
> renderer process (index.html) this is not and will not be supported.
> In the renderer process use `fetch` instead

An example of usage of `fetch`:

```
fetch('https://github.com/')
                .then(res => res.text())
                .then(body => console.log(body))
```

Ps.
You may also have a problem with Content Security Policy just like me. In this case, an other answer helps: [Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852682/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po)