# because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, jenkins

I wrote a program that generated an html file with this header:

[image]

but I don't have `iframe` at all, let alone in sandbox

[image]

When I open the page in the browser (hosted on a Jenkins server) I see no css.

These are the errors (security policy)

[image]

I have seen some posts on stockoverflow, saying the `<meta>` should be like:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8 ;">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' http://onlineerp.solution.quebec 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com">
```

but as you can see in my print screen that didn't help

any idea, how can I fix this?

Comment: This is due to security changes in Jenkins, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/34681852/172599

Comment: why downvote? I don't get it

Comment: There are a number of things that could be improved in this post: 1) the title does not explain the problem ("Why is CSS blocked by the Content Security Policy in my document"), 2) the error messages are only shown in a small font in an image (which makes them both hard to read and non-searchable), 3) the phrase "but I don't have iframe at all, let alone in sandbox" makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks
1) I'm used to search posts in SOF by error text. So I thought this will make this post more searchable
2) the images are easy so click and expand. No small fonts 3) makes no sense to me as well. That's why i asked and couldn't use answers from other posts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blocked script execution in <URL>. because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315723/blocked-script-execution-in-url-because-the-documents-frame-is-sandboxed-and)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're serving an HTML page from Jenkins, so Jenkins controls the response headers, not your content. Recent [security fixes](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/SECURITY/Jenkins+Security+Advisory+2015-12-09) in Jenkins imposed a strict default [Content Security Policy](http://content-security-policy.com). You should be able to see the Content-Security-Policy header inserted by Jenkins in the response headers.

One solution is to relax the Jenkins configuration, see the [Configuring Content Security Policy wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy) for details:

> The CSP header sent by Jenkins can be modified by setting the system property *hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP*:
>
> If its value is the empty string, e.g. `java -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP= -jar jenkins.war` then the header will not be sent at all.
>
> (Warning!) This is potentially very unsafe and should only be used after reviewing the overall security setup.

You can experiment with different settings using the [Jenkins Script Console](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console). To enable CSS and images from external sites, you could use something like:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox; default-src 'self'; img-src '*'; style-src '*' 'unsafe-inline';")
```

Another solution is to publish (deploy) the generated page(s) on another server where you can control the content security policy.

Comment: yes. I see `"Content-Security-Policy:sandbox; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';"`

Comment: is there any solution where i continue deploying on jenkins and not relaxing jenkins to all files on our team machine?