# Refused to load the stylesheet because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"

Tags: html, css, content-security-policy

I m trying to load an external popup form created with a third-party tool. 
I keep getting this error about CSP violations. Thing is I can load them correctly locally and they are only blocked when I deploy them on my provider's server. I dont know where these policies are coming from since I havent defined anything in .htaccess file (PHP web app with codeigniter)
I checked all the relevant answers but nothing worked for me.

[Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211359/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po)

[because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014990/because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-policy-directive-style-src)

I also tried several versions of
 `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"`  but again no luck.

[image]

Comment: did you try to read the answers to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211359/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po

Comment: Yep I read all similar answers in stackoverflow. Nothing worked for me. As if the csp rules are imposed/overriden by the server settings? Is this possible? I asked my provider but they couldnt help either

Comment: Is the document served with a Content-Security-Policy HTTP response header? If so, you can’t use a meta element in the document to set a policy that overrides the policy in that Content-Security-Policy header; instead to update the policy you must change the value of that header. You need for the policy to be `style-src 'self' https://assets.privy.com https://downloads.mailchimp.com 'unsafe-inline'` (though note that any time you’re putting 'unsafe-inline' into a CSP, you basically might as well not be specifying a CSP policy at all — because 'unsafe-inline' defeats the entire purpose of CSP…)

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy

Answer (score -2):

It needs to be fixed on the server side. Please update the policy on server.