# Angular ngRoute can't load template: Error [$compile:tpload]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I tried some simple Angular Routing, but I cant specify what's the error. Chrome just tells me that Angular can't compile the Template.

In the following Link you can see my directory structure.

[directory-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BknYq.png)

-- angular.js

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);

testApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/list.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    }).when('/insert', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/new.html',
        controller: 'newController'
    });
});


testApp.controller('mainController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'main';
});

testApp.controller('newController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'new';
});
```

--index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="testApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Barfly</title>
    <script src="/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angularApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <a href="#list">list</a>
    <a href="#insert">new</a>
    <div id="main">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my error,

[Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXcHl.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `templateUrl` should be like `templateUrl: '/pages/list.html',`

Comment: just tried it and the error still occurs

Comment: Can you put this on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT. Sorry, I didn't see your directory structure. Are you sure pages directory is accessible to the public? Should the pages directory be moved into public directory?

Old answer:

The error is saying the templateUrl **/pages/list.html** does not exists. You should either save a template file into /pages/list.html file or add an inline template in the html body like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/pages/list.html">
my template here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a sort of similar problem: `templateUrl` files could be not loaded (all resources didn't). In my case it happened when app was loaded on a browser on a mobile device. It was caused by Content Security Policy restrictions ([How does Content Security Policy work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280370/how-does-content-security-policy-work))

I got the CSP to permit all resources **except** for the templates referenced by `templateUrl`.
I also tried loading the templates through the `script` directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script), but to no avail.

Eventually I decided to embed the templates in the route itself, like this:

```
testApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/list', {
        template: '<li ng-repeat="etcetera"></li>',
        controller: 'mainController'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a data-target="#list">list</a>
<a data-target="#insert">new</a>
```

Comment: angular's herf with # is other mean.