# Chrome "Unsafe attempt to load URL" on same Domains, protocols and ports

Tags: html, xml, xslt, jenkins, content-security-policy

In Chrome when I try and access the xml link shown in the error below I get this error.

> Unsafe attempt to load URL http://build:8080/view/application/job/Project/Report/SourceMonitor.xslt from frame with URL http://build:8080/view/application/job/Project/Report/SourceMonitor-details.xml. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

As far as I can see the Domain, protocol and port are the same.
The files are both hosted on a Jenkins CI web server so it is not because it is local files.
It works when I open the xml file in Internet Explorer.
The xml file links to the xslt with the xml tag shown below.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="SourceMonitor.xslt"?>
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same problem with out internal Jenkins infrastructure, but it is easily reproducible with the Jenkins Docker image by running it according to its documentation and having a pipeline job producing a XSLT file and a XML file that references that XSLT file. Opening the XML via the workspace folder in the *Node Allocate node : Start* will fail and Chrome will output the error as stated by the question.

This is not limited to Chrome though as Firefox will report an error as well, looking something like:

> Error loading stylesheet: A network error occurred loading an XSLT stylesheet `http://build:8080/view/application/job/Project/Report/SourceMonitor.xslt`

Solving this is a matter of configuring the Content Security Policy (CSP) Jenkins uses. How Content Security Policy works is explained here: [Stackoverflow: How does Content Security Policy work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30280370/3943720).

The default CSP configuration for Jenkins is very strict and will not allow a XSL file to be loaded from a document referencing it. The default CSP configuration and how to change it is documented on the Jenkins wiki page.

According to CSP documentation (CR-CSP-20121115 chapter 4.2 script-src) XSL style sheets are treated as scripts and I had to add `script-src 'self';` and `sandbox allow-same-origin;` to the default configuration to make a simple XSL style sheet work. I did this via the Jenkins *Script Console* by running:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP","sandbox allow-same-origin; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; script-src 'self';")
```

Using `System.setProperty` changes CSP temporarily until next reboot, it is all documented on the Jenkins wiki page.

Look for any further errors reported by Chrome or other browser because content in the XSLT file may require you to relax other CSP rules as well, such as allowing style tags to be interpreted.