# How to prevent google ads from displaying console messages or uncaught errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense, console.log

**Is there a way to block the google ads scripts from displaying any console messages?**

(also in their third party script that may run)

My concern is that sometimes I see messages such as the one below loading large object and uncaught errors that may end up slowing down the client

[image]

[image]

Locally it really goes out of control:

[image]

Comment: you are overthinking things

Comment: I don't think so, sometimes I'm getting uncaught errors in a loop (thousands per minute) that really slow down the browser

Comment: AFAIK the effect of the console itself should be very small if you don't have it open. The code that's throwing thousands of errors is more likely to cause the slowdown itself.

Comment: Yes, very irritating. Especially how it clutters down the console while debugging. One of my ads has a slider with 20 slides and each slide is printed to the console log as an object

Comment: Actually I find a solution - it works 99% of the time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585680/how-to-block-google-ads-from-injecting-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not perfect, but it seems to be very effective in my case (all pages are SSL) and also prevent SSL mixed mode messages caused by google ads third party plugin scripts...

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests; object-src 'none'">
```

Content-Security-Policy is critical to prevent mixed content errors (too many errors can show a "connection not secure" by the browser and memory leaks) https://blog.cloudflare.com/fixing-the-mixed-content-problem-with-automatic-https-rewrites and How does [Content Security Policy work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280370/how-does-content-security-policy-work)