# Is it ok to put line-breaks in add_header in nginx configuration?

Tags: nginx

I've searched on this topic and can't find anything in the nginx configuration that says if this is "ok" or not?

This appears to work just fine, other than messing up the syntax highlighting in vim:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' *.google-analytics.com;
                                     object-src 'none';
                                     report-uri /csp-report;";
```

But is it actually valid?  Am I relying on browsers understanding line breaks inside a CSP, or does nginx render it into one line before serving it?  Fiddler appears to show it as one line, but again I don't know if nginx is serving it as that or if Fiddler is interpreting it as that.

(This is obviously a much simplified version of my true CSP, which is certainly very much long enough that I consider it beneficial to my sanity to split it onto multiple lines!)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unfortunately, `nginx` treats the white space between the quotes literally, so as long as you begin each new line with a space or tab character, the header will remain valid.

However, it is possible to create an invalid header. For example, this produces an invalid header:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' *.google-analytics.com;
object-src 'none';
report-uri /csp-report;";
```

The support for splitting header lines is deprecated in RFC 7230:

From [RFC 7230 section 3.2.4](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc7230.pdf)

> Historically, HTTP header field values could be extended over
>   multiple lines by preceding each extra line with at least one space
>   or horizontal tab (obs-fold).  This specification deprecates such
>   line folding except within the message/http media type

The safest solution would be to accept that some lines in your configuration file may be very much longer than you would prefer.

Comment: Even if nginx allows you to create multi-lines headers, some other components of your system (a corporate proxy in my case) may not be able to handle them correctly.
This may lead to hard to debug issues so I would recommend keeping them on one line, even if it's hard to read.

Comment: observed exactly this problem with nginx 1.17: for Content-Security-Policy we had huge section previously divided to multiple lines. We started to observe strange urls in this header like "https //abc.com" so the solution was to create just one long line.

Comment: This really sucks. It's both harder to read diffs and harder to audit the CSP if it's one massive line.

Answer (score 61):

You can use variable nesting like this, which still in the end creates a one liner:

```
set $SCRIPT "script-src 'self'";
set $SCRIPT "${SCRIPT} https://www.a.com"; # comment each line if you like
set $SCRIPT "${SCRIPT} https://b.com";
set $STYLE "style-src 'self'";
set $STYLE "${STYLE} https://a.com";
set $IMG "img-src 'self' data:";
set $IMG "${IMG} https://a.com";
set $IMG "${IMG} https://www.b.com";
set $FONT "font-src 'self' data:";
set $FONT "${FONT} https://a.com";
set $DEFAULT "default-src 'self'";
set $CONNECT "connect-src 'self'";
set $CONNECT "${CONNECT} https://www.a.com";
set $CONNECT "${CONNECT} https://www.b.com";
set $FRAME "frame-src 'self'";
set $FRAME "${FRAME} https://a.com";
set $FRAME "${FRAME} https://b.com";
add_header Content-Security-Policy "${SCRIPT}; ${STYLE}; ${IMG}; ${FONT}; ${DEFAULT}; ${CONNECT}; ${FRAME}";
```

Comment: Thank you. This should be the accepted answer. Working perfectly.