# Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff.....'it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

My react webApp give this Error in Browser Console

```
Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff;base64,d09........' because it` 
`violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src` `'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

**Also:**

```
Refused to connect to 'ws://localhost:3000/sockjs-node/782/oawzy1fx/websocket' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

**Screenshot of browser console**
[image]

**index.html** Have this **meta:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:; default-src 'self' http://121.0.0:3000/">
```

**WebPack.cofig.js**

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "./src"),
    devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : true,
    entry: "../src/index.js",

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/i,  // a regular expression that catches .js files
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|.jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react','es2016', 'stage-0',],
                    plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties'],
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, "src"),
            "node_modules",
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/public/",
        // publicPath: "/public/",
        filename: "build.js"
    },
    plugins: debug ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
    ],
    devServer: {
        port: 3000, // most common port
        contentBase: './public',
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
    }
};
```

Comment: can you try <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:; default-src 'self' http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8084/mypp/">

Comment: nothing change `    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:; default-src 'self' http://121.0.0:3000/">;
`  still give Error

Answer (score 298, accepted):

For me it was because of the Chrome extension 'Grammarly'. After disabling that, I did not get the error.

Comment: What a silly hack for this. can't even imagine the problem is due to Grammarly chrome app.

Comment: I can't believe I spent couple of hours trying to realize what was going on and it was being caused by Grammarly app. Just remove that tash!

Comment: Dangit, Grammarly! I had two other developers helping me with this issue to no resolve. We thought we incorrectly implemented our content security policy. Removed my Grammarly expension from Chrome and the errors went away. Thanks or this tip!

Comment: Note: only "disabling" on the plugin config dropdown is not enough, you have to remove or disable it on the chrome plugins pages

Comment: Same issue with my Angular app. This fixed it right up!

Comment: OMG, Thanks for this, I assigned this as an issue to the my angular developer. I should close that issue now.

Comment: What the hell with grammerly :S

Comment: LOL this is ilarious (sorry for my grammar, I disabled Grammarly xD )

Comment: How the hell you find this out? I did google for half hour but at last your answer yielded results.. Thanks Girl!!

Comment: Yeah this was the issue -__-

Comment: I had to disable the Markdown Viewer v3.9 Chrome Extension ID ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk

Comment: The same happened to me on Grammarly for Firefox and Safari

Comment: The `Save to Pocket` extension can also cause this in Edge and Chrome.

Comment: Removing the "Save to Pocket Extension" worked for me as well. @johnbt Do you have a workaround for making sure I can use the extension still without it breaking my browsing experience

Comment: @anshuman-kumar: No sorry... just wanted to share the information in case it would be helpful to anyone else. Maybe getpocket support can help you though.

Comment: Yeah I have reported the bug to them @johnbt

Comment: @sevenam Jesus Christ; I've spent over an hour looking for the cause. I'll go file a bug report too.

Answer (score 137):

To fix this specific error, CSP should include this:

```
font-src 'self' data:;
```

So, index.html meta should read:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="font-src 'self' data:; img-src 'self' data:; default-src 'self' http://121.0.0:3000/">
```

Comment: Thanks this solves the problem as well.
Consider that for some users it is not viable to disable the extension, and your site will avoid issues with any possible extension loading assets locally :)

Comment: I think this will leave your site insecure to bad extensions and would advise against it without further research.

Comment: Is it required to specify `http://121.0.0:3000/` while using 'self' already ?

Comment: THIS is why stackoverflow exists! Thank you so much @nourish

Comment: So, my answer is popular, but, to everyone who is going to use it: make sure you understand security implications as well. Spend some time and read something useful about content security policies.

Answer (score 30):

For what it's worth - I had a similar issue, assuming it's related to a Chrome update.

I had to add font-src, and then specify the url because I was using a CDN

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' data: fonts.gstatic.com;">
```

Comment: but I was Use Fonts from my local computer so what i will be write hare ?? `data: fonts.gstatic.com`

Comment: @JavaScriptLearner - in that case you can just try data:

Answer (score 18):

From personal experience, it is always a best, first step to run your site in Incognito (Chrome), Private Browsing (Firefox), and InPrivate (IE11 && Edge) to remove the interference of add-ons/extensions. These can still interfere with testing in this mode if they are enabled explicitly in their settings. However, it is an easy first step to troubleshooting an issue.

The reason I am here, was due to Web of Trust (WoT) adding content to my page, and my page having had very strict Content Security Policy:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; font-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:; img-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self';"
```

This caused many errors. I was looking more for an answer on how to tell the extension to not try and run on this site programatically. This way when people have extensions, they just won't run on my site. I imagine if this were possible, ad blockers would have been banned on sites long ago. So my research is a bit naive. Hope this helps anyone else trying to diagnose an issue that is not specifically tied to the handful of mentioned extensions in other answers.

Comment: Yeah I had a whole bunch of CSP-Report-Only (I'm just using Report-Only for now) errors in the Dev Tools console but they didn't make sense and were referring to a CSP that apppeared out of date since I had modified it.

I disabled the "Content Security Policy Generator" extension and that fixed those weird errors, lol.

Answer (score 14):

You may need to add this to `webpack.config.js`:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I was facing similar issue.

1. You need to remove all the CSP parameter which are picked up by default and understand why each attribute is required.

font-src - is to tell the browser to load the font's from src which is specified after that.
font-src: 'self' - this tells to load font family within the same origin or system.
font-src: 'self' data: - this tells load font-family within the same origin and the calls made to get data:

You might also get warning "** Failed to decode downloaded font, OTS parsing error: invalid version tag **" Add the following entry in CSP.

font-src: 'self' font

This should now load with no errors.

Answer (score 3):

CSP helps you whitelisting sources that you trust. All other sources are not allowed access to. Read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280370/how-does-content-security-policy-work) carefully, and then make sure that you whitelist the fonts, socket connections and other sources **if you trust them**.

If you know what you are doing, you can comment out the `meta` tag to test, probably everything works. But realise that you / your user is being protected here, so keeping the `meta` tag is probably a good thing.

Comment: Thanks For Nice answer but Still I can solve  `Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff;base64,d09` this error

Comment: But this meta Solve Maximum Error:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;"`

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same error in my node application today.

[image]

Below was my node API.

```
app.get('azureTable', (req, res) => {
  const tableSvc = azure.createTableService(config.azureTableAccountName, config.azureTableAccountKey);
  const query = new azure.TableQuery().top(1).where('PartitionKey eq ?', config.azureTablePartitionKey);
  tableSvc.queryEntities(config.azureTableName, query, null, (error, result, response) => {
    if (error) { return; }
    res.send(result);
    console.log(result)
  });
});
```

The fix was very simple, I was missing a slash "/" before my API. So after changing the path from 'azureTable' to '/azureTable', the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.
I had mentioned a wrong output folder path in angular.json

```
"outputPath": "dist/",

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The browser extension uBlock’s setting [“Block remote fonts”](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Per-site-switches#no-remote-fonts) will cause this error. (Note: Grammarly was not the problem, at least for me.)

Usually this isn’t a problem. When a remote font is blocked, you fall back to some other font and a console warning saying “ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT” is issued. However, this can be a serious problem when a site uses Font Awesome, because the icons show as boxes.

There’s not much a website can do about fixing this (but you can prevent it from being too bad by e.g. labeling font-based icons). Changing the CSP (or adding one) will not fix it. Serving the fonts from your website (and not a CDN) will not fix it either.

The uBlock user, on the other hand, has the power to fix this by doing one of the following:

- Uncheck the option globally in the dashboard for the extension
- Navigate to your website and click on the extension icon, then on the [crossed out ‘A’ icon](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/585534/46021462-b9de5b80-c0ae-11e8-82d9-f763bcd841ca.png) to not block fonts just for that site
- Disable uBlock for your site by adding it to the whitelist in the extension’s dashboard

Answer (score 1):

You would have used inline styles at many places, which CSP(Content Security Policy) prohibits because it could be dangerous.

**Just try removing those inline styles and put it inside dedicated stylesheet.**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and which got resolved by using `./` before the directory name in my `node.js` app, i.e.

`app.use(express.static('./public'));`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a part of code I use to direct my server.js file to angular **dist** folder, which was created after **npm build**

```
// Create link to Angular build directory
var distDir = __dirname + "/dist/";
app.use(express.static(distDir));
```

I fixed it by changing
`"/dist/"` to `"./dist/"`

Answer (score 1):

For me it was because of ipfs extension in brave browser

Answer (score 0):

If your project is vue-cli and you run `npm run build` you should change

`assetsPublicPath: '/'` to  `assetsPublicPath'./'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turns out there was an error in the directory of the file I was trying to serve 
instead of:

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../dist'));
```

I had :

```js
app.use(express.static('./dist'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue today in my running code.
 Well, I found a lot of answers here. But the important thing I want to mention is that this error message is quite ambiguous and doesn't explicitly point out the exact error.

Some faced it due to browser extensions, some due to incorrect URL patterns and I faced this due to an error in my formGroup instance used in a pop-up in that screen.
So, I would suggest everyone that before making any new changes in your code, please debug your code and verify that you don't have any such errors. 
You will certainly find the actual reason by debugging.

If nothing else works then check your URL as that is the most common reason for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my laravel & VueJS project I solved this error with webpack.mix.js file. It contains

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.webpackConfig({
   devServer: {
     proxy: {
       '*': 'http://localhost:8000'
     }
   },
   resolve: {
     alias: {
       "@": path.resolve(
         __dirname,
         "resources/assets/js"
       )
     }
   }
 });

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Answer (score 0):

if it says report only, refused to execute content policy error. Then the warning can be ignored and it may be caused by the page shield feature on cloudflare.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I deleted **src/registerServiceWorker** file from create-react-app generated app. I added it and now it's all working.

Answer (score -1):

Running my frontend application on a different port worked for me.

Initially I had `ng serve --port 3000`
which I later changed to `ng serve --port 5000`