# Refused to load the font '<URL>' console error for nextcloud

Tags: javascript, security, fonts, nextcloud

I recently built a document portal with NEXTCLOUD (PHP and MySQL), which is working fine, but for some reason, now I receive this error on my console:

```
Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'self'".
```

Sometimes it is repeated 22 times, some other times more than a hundred. I tried to debug in a different way, changing my .htaccess file adding an instance but it didn't work and I'm trying to figure it out if there any other way to exclude that font from loading.

I tried to figure it out what is happening under the hat and I find out that the problem is in the core.js file:

```
core.js?v=eac5ba96-53:4 Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAGVUABEAAAAAxuQAAQABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABHREVGAAABgAAAAC4AAAA0ArgC7UdQT1MAAAGwAAAQ6AAALgxKsqRTR1NVQgAAEpgAAAH3AAAELqI5y+RPUy8yAAAUkAAAAE8AAABgaGyBu2NtYXAAABTgAAABlAAAAkQkRATXY3Z0IAAAFnQAAABeAAAAugDsQf1mcGdtAAAW1AAABZcAAAvNb3/BHGdhc3AAABxsAAAACAAAAAgAAAAQZ2x5ZgAAHHQAAEApAAB3CtbiupxoZWFkAABcoAAAADYAAAA2BkubWWhoZWEAAFzYAAAAIAAAACQHFARfaG10eAAAXPgAAAI6AAAEEk4TN4Nsb2NhAABfNAAAAhIAAAISiLhpam1heHAAAGFIAAAAIAAAACACigzgbmFtZQAAYWgAAACUAAABHhQGLdJwb3N0AABh/AAAAq4AAASRk5y6n3ByZ...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'self'".

offset @ core.js?v=eac5ba96-53:4
(anonymous) @ core.js?v=eac5ba96-53:13
(anonymous) @ core.js?v=eac5ba96-53:13
(anonymous) @ core.js?v=eac5ba96-53:13
```

I checked the very file but I didn't find any line where that particular font could be hidden.

Anyone who had this problem before?

Comment: Probably related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366744/refused-to-load-the-font-datafont-woff-it-violates-the-following-content

Comment: I tried to add a line on my head but it didn't work