# Trouble in Routing

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, react-router-dom, react-router-redux

I am using `react-router-dom` and `react-router-redux` for routing in React. I am unable to route to the relative path. In my case '/login.

Here is the code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/y73931q871

Also if I run the code in the local it throws:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In **webpack.config.js**, you should not miss `historyApiFallback: true` for the devServer object. Something like this:

```
  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
```

Also, in your Route configuration, you need to reorder the Routes like

```
export const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

`re-order` is needed because `Switch` only renders the first matched route and a path like `/login` will also match `/` and hence only render `Home` all the time, so all paths that are prefixed to other paths need to be placed at the end.

**[working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/owwnrv9p5)**

Comment: I reordered them for debugging. Sorry. Great! it's working in the codesandbox, but it's throwing the same error in my browser with the local setup. Possibly some version conflicts. I have updated my ques with package.json. Let me know if you can help me with that. Thanks.

Comment: @ChasingUnicorn, as I said, the errors are not related to Route but to fonts that you might be loading,  please check the font that you are loading on login page

Comment: Also, if fonts loading is the issue, then my Home page would have also thrown the same error.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366744/refused-to-load-the-font-datafont-woff-it-violates-the-following-content/45563020

Comment: Thanks, @shubham, but that post I already saw. Anyway, I got the solution. Have updated your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#exact-bool), you should use `exact` prop with index (`/`) route.

So the code should looks like this:

```
export const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your home route by the following and it will work as you want

```
    <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
```