# ERROR in pathType.isDirectory is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am geting an error `ERROR in pathType.isDirectory is not a function` whenever I run `ng serve` in the terminal. When checking the console the error says:

`Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:4200/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`   as well as the classic 404.

I have tried deleting the favicon.ico as well as updating to the latest versions of node, npm and angular to no avail. Any suggestions/help on how I can debug this?

Comment: Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440876/refused-to-load-the-image-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-pol)

Answer (score 15):

Wasn't sure about the core of the problem but if this happens to anybody maybe this will work. I deleted the `node_modules` of my project and reran `npm install` to refresh my project.

Comment: I can confirm. Had the error -> deleted node-modules and package-lock -> yarn install back everything this time and it works again like a charm.