# Get error from font cannot access database

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I have start a new project Laravel/vue it's a Pwa. I have 3-4 Database in phpmyadmin, i try to access him now but i can't "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/" display me the nice picture oh php and welcome in phpmyadmin but nothing else !

In my log i got that :

`Refused to load the font 'data:application/x-font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09G.......A=' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' ". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

So i try to don't run my project or other project but all time i got that ! So where the error from ?? Is not in my project i thinks

More informations:

Mysql

Xampp

Linux(Ubuntu)

Edit:

So other browser load him and all work so i think is become Google chrome anyone now how can i do ?

Thanks you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff.....'it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366744/refused-to-load-the-font-datafont-woff-it-violates-the-following-content)

Comment: Thanks, but i see before and is don't work. I have not this extension, and is become google chrome not project actually i do my project on chromuin and phpmyadmin work it on it.
So if anyone got idea i take it because i love google chrome :(