# Material Icons in framework7 load on pc browser but not in Android app

Tags: android, jquery, html, html-framework-7, google-material-icons

I'm writing an app using Framework7 and I need some material icons. I added in the html file the path for the material icons provided by them:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then i called icons using the tag:

```
<i class="material-icons">icon_name_here</i>
```

Well, when I load the app in the pc browser icons are correctly rendered, but when I upload the code to Adobe PhoneGap that builds the .apk, when I install it on a device and run it the app loads but the icons are not rendered, instead I read their names.

What do I can do to solve the prob? 
Thank guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a Content Security Policy issue. I build from my PC using Cordova and have never uploaded to Adobe Phonegap, but I imagine Phonegap does enforce some security by limiting the sources of data to your app. If indeed it is Content Security Policy issue, you will have to explicitly declare googleapis.com as a possible source of content for your app.

You can find details of implementing Content Security Policy in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280370/how-does-content-security-policy-work)