# Change URI directly for a Vue app and caused error

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuejs2

In my Vue app, I can click a link generated by `<router-link>...</router-link>` and visit a page like: `/site/books/00666.html`.

The routing config for this is:

```
{
  path: '/books/:id.html',
  name: 'BookDetail',
  component: BookDetail,
  props: true,
}
```

So I changed the URI in the browser (Fx57) to: `/site/books/00777.html` to try to display the detail information of another book. It failed with this:

> Cannot get /books/00777.html

and the debugger told me something like:

> Content security policy is preventing from accessing a resource from 'self'`.

I searched on CSP but can't figure out how to make this working.

**Update:** To reproduce the issue, I use `vue init webpack test` and scafolded a blank Vue app with router support.

1. One new router is added: 

   `{
   path: '/book/:id.html',
   name: 'BookDetail',
   component: BookDetail,
   props: true,
   }`
2. In the default `HelloWorld.vue`, just add a few lines with `<router-link>`:

`<ul>
      <li><router-link :to="{name: 'BookDetail', params: {id: 12345} }">Book 1</router-link></li>
      <li><router-link :to="{name: 'BookDetail', params: {id: 23456} }">Book 2</router-link></li>
  </ul>`

3. In the HelloWorld page, clicking the link above will take you to "localhost:8080/book/12345.html". Good.
4. Change the URI to "localhost:8080/book/23456.html". The browser prompts the same error as before.

**Update 2**： per hint below, I modified the URI pattern to '/books/:id' and it is working.

Further question: What shall I do if I want to add the `.html` suffix?

Comment: Can you add some code or create a fiddle reproducing it, do you see any error in console?

Comment: I believe that is not related to the codings but related to the routing machanism in Vue. @Saurabh

Comment: might help:https://stackoverflow.com/q/30280370/1610034

Comment: I think the problem is `.html`. Have you tried to remove it?

Comment: @imcvampire Yes! You are right! I have never thought of this could be the issue！

Comment: About the new update, do you use any web proxy like `nginx` ...?