# CSP error when trying to load CDNs to a Play Framework application

Tags: jquery, playframework, cdn

I am new to  Play Framework and i was attempting to put the jquery CDN to my play application. Every time I put any kind of CDN into my view files (scala.html extension) i keep getting a CSP error saying:

```
Refused to load the script 
'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js' because 
it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 
'self'". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is 
used as a fallback.
```

I referred [How does Content Security Policy work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280370/how-does-content-security-policy-work) and added the meta tag elements accordingly and also referred the http://content-security-policy.com/
but still could not get it to work.

I would really appriciate if anyone could help me out. Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the `application.conf` file, where you don't have setup correctly the parameter `play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy`.

For reference see [this page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#SecurityHeadersFilter)

Comment: You are correct, that was the problem. I figured it out a little late, it was stupid of me to not check the application.config file first.

Answer (score 0):

Luca T.'s answer was correct. I am putting this to give a more detailed answer in case if anyone else stumbles upon the same problem.

To get the CSP error to go away i had to add:

```
contentSecurityPolicy = null
```

in the application.conf file's 'play.filters.headers' section as shown below:

[image]

**NOTE:** It is not good for the security of the application, but if you are just trying to make a simple application, this gets the job done.