# Incorporating Content Security Policy (CSP) in R-Notebook

Tags: r, knitr, content-security-policy, rnotebook

I am very new to the R Notebook universe and have been blown away by the ease and efficiency of the R Notebook --> knitr --> HTML workflow. I have mainly been using the [rmdformts](https://github.com/juba/rmdformats) and [Tufte](https://rstudio.github.io/tufte/) templates.

My institution has recently implemented something called Content Security Policy (CSP, e.g. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280370/how-does-content-security-policy-work) ) on its servers. Now all the beautiful 'knitr(ed)'' web pages are displayed without CSS and Javascript.

Can someone please advise how to incorporate the correct CSP  into the R-Notebook so that knitr includes it under the HTML meta tag?

Many thanks!

Comment: Messing with whether CSS and Javascript are inlined may help, maybe `self_contained: false`? See https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#document_dependencies

Comment: @dash2 Your suggestion was spot on. This created local folders that keep the CSP happy. Thank you!

Comment: I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that may work is to include

```
self_contained: false
```

in the YAML header of the rmarkdown document.