# js onclick random text using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make this script work addEventListener.
If you click on the button you should get a random text from the array.
However, I’m not a javascript king. Please help me.

```js
 function GetValue()
      {
          var whys = new Array(
              "why 1",
              "why 2",
              "why 3"
              );
         var random = whys[Math.floor(Math.random() * whys.length)];
         var btn = document.getElementById("message");
         btn.addEventListener("click", GetValue, false);
      }
```

```html
<span class="why_title" id="message">Ask Why!<br/>And Ask it Again<br/>And again</span>


<button class="why_btn" onclick="GetValue();">Ask Why Again!</button>
```

Comment: Put `btn.addEventListener("click", GetValue, false);` and the definition of `btn`. outside of `GetValue`. You probably don’t want to bind a new event with every click.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define 'btn' variable outside the GetValue "Function" scope.
And use EventListener from global scope so that you can invoke the function, when button got click.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("why_btn");

function GetValue()
{
  var whys = new Array(
      "why 1",
      "why 2",
      "why 3"
  );
    var random = whys[Math.floor(Math.random() * whys.length)];
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += '<br>' + random;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", GetValue);
```

```html
<span class="why_title" id="message">Ask Why!<br/>And Ask it Again<br/>And again</span>
    <button id="why_btn">Ask Why Again!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I observe couple of thing need to modified in your JavaScript code :

1. addEventListener - Binding with wrong element :

   `<button class="why_btn" onclick="GetValue();">Ask Why Again!</button>`

   click event already handle from JavaScript, So remove `onclick` attributes from button tag.

   **Your JavaScript Code Snippet :**

   `var btn = document.getElementById("message");`

   `btn.addEventListener("click", GetValue, false);`
2. `btn.addEventListener("click", GetValue, false);` - declare outside the function

**Solutions :**

```js
function GetValue() {
     var whys = new Array(
         "why 1",
         "why 2",
         "why 3"
     );
     var random = whys[Math.floor(Math.random() * whys.length)];
     document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = random;
 }
 //var btn = document.getElementById("message");
 var btn = document.querySelector(".why_btn");
 btn.addEventListener("click", GetValue, false);
```

```html
<span class="why_title" id="message">Ask Why!<br/>And Ask it Again<br/>And again</span>


<button class="why_btn">Ask Why Again!</button>
```

Hope it's helpful :)

Comment: it is! It works perfect, only I have to add <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https:"> in the header and then the script isnt working anymore. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score -2):

You are adding event listener to text, not button.

```js
 

    function GetValue()
          {
              var whys = new Array(
                  "why 1",
                  "why 2",
                  "why 3"
                  );
             var random = whys[Math.floor(Math.random() * whys.length)];
             alert(random);
             
          }
var btn = document.getElementById("message");
btn.addEventListener("click", GetValue, false);
```

```html
<span class="why_title">Ask Why!<br/>And Ask it Again<br/>And again</span>


<button id="message" class="why_btn" onclick="GetValue();">Ask Why Again!</button>
```

Comment: It works perfect, only I have to add <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https:"> in the header and then the script isnt working anymore. Do you have a solution?

Comment: if it's because of inline scripts, try this..

content="script-src 'unsafe-inline';

reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280370/how-does-content-security-policy-work

Comment: tnx for the reference