# How to modify CSP in joomla website on http header

Tags: php, joomla, google-tag-manager

When I use `google tag manager` codes on my Joomla website it shows the following error.

> Refused to load the script
>   'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-T44GGZR' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src
>   'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'

I changed the CSP on meta tag but still not working.

How can I change the CSP in http

Comment: improved the grammer

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280370/how-does-content-security-policy-work