# Content Security Policy - external HTML

Tags: html, content-security-policy

## G'day Developer Superheros!

Using `default-src 'none'` to block everything that’s not explicitly whitelisted elsewhere in the CSP. The only thing I'm struggling with is external HTML loaded by Stripe payment processor and ShareThis social sharing buttons.

Typical violations are `htm` and `html` URLs:

> `https://t.sharethis.com/a/t_.htm`
> `https://js.stripe.com/v3/m-outer-ff599b5032b79ea1f89ba5416bea26e6.html`

I can't figure out the correct policy directive/resource type to allow `htm` and `html` URLs.

I'm trying to avoid adding these to `default-src`
Can you please offer guidance or suggestions that might work?

> My question is unique in that the suggested duplicate does not identify the correct directive to allow `htm` and `html` URLs.

Much Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Content Security Policy (CSP) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280370/how-does-content-security-policy-csp-work)

Comment: `htm` and `html` URLs you shown should be covered by `frame-src` directive. But you are able to figure out it exactly, just check browser console. Firefox: `Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://example.com/page.php ("frame-src")`. Chrome: `Refused to frame 'https://example.com/page.php' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'none'"`. Both violation messages related to `frame-src` directive.

Comment: Thanks for the info and recommendation, @granty I'll use the `frame-src` directive as you suggested. Before asking this question, Firefox dev console reported these `htm` and `html` URLs had violated my `default-src 'none'` directive. Hopefully, the `frame-src` suggestion will work. BIG thanks, @granty .

Comment: If some fallback-directive is omitted, the [nearest fallback](https://csplite.com/csp62/#final_fallback) (`default-src` finally) is used, therefore it's shown as [violated-directive](https://csplite.com/csp66/#violated-directive). You can make a trick - add all unused fallback-directives with `'none'` key. This is full list: `child-src 'none'; connect-src 'none'; font-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; img-src 'none'; manifest-src 'none'; media-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; prefetch-src 'none'; script-src 'none'; style-src 'none'; worker-src 'none';`, just remove directives used in your CSP.

Comment: I tried adding the `htm` and `html` URLs to the `frame-src` directive but continued getting CSP violations.  

I'm happy to report, adding the `htm` and `html` URLs to the `child-src` directive fixed the problem. No more violations now.  

Why didn't this work when adding to the `frame-src` directive? Maybe has something to do with browser support. I believe in CSP Level 2 `frame-src` was deprecated in favour of the `child-src` directive. Then CSP Level 3, undepreciated `frame-src`. Maybe not all browsers have caught up with the change.  

I appreciate your help, @granty