# What is causing "Refused to load the script... because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive..." with my configuration?

Tags: javascript, playframework, content-security-policy

My project is using Scala Play Framework 2.8.19. My configuration for the Content Security Policy filter is as follows:

```
play.filters.csp {
  directives {
    default-src = "'self'"
    img-src = "'self' *.fbcdn.net *.twimg.com *.googleusercontent.com *.xingassets.com vk.com *.yimg.com secure.gravatar.com chart.googleapis.com *.fbsbx.com api.qrserver.com"
    style-src = "'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdnjs.cloudflare.com maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com cdn.jsdelivr.net fonts.googleapis.com"
    font-src = "'self' fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com"
    script-src = ${play.filters.csp.directives.script-src} "'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com"
    connect-src = "'self' twitter.com *.xing.com"
  }
}
```

If I disable the CSP filter, I'm able to load the script. With it enabled, I get the following error in Chrome:

> Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:9000/static/js/main.291e8d2b.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-m7r6oxzmy1TvABLGWrCMAA==' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' https: http: 'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com". Note that 'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based allowlisting is disabled. Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

At first, the script-src was:

```
    script-src = ${play.filters.csp.directives.script-src} "cdnjs.cloudflare.com"
```

... but I tried adding 'self' - not really knowing what I'm doing:

```
    script-src = ${play.filters.csp.directives.script-src} "'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Content Security Policy (CSP) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280370/how-does-content-security-policy-csp-work)

Answer (score 0):

Please read https://content-security-policy.com/strict-dynamic/. Adding 'strict-dynamic' to you policy disables http: https: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval'. This is added in the filter for backward compatibility for browsers that don't understand 'strict-dynamic'.

You will either have to build your own script-src directive without the provided filter, or make your referenced code adhere to 'strict-dynamic' by providing the correct nonce value.